# PHP PDO Transaction Management across multiple write methods on different classes

Tags: php, pdo, transactions

I need help architecting an appropriate approach to managing transaction across multiple writes over multiple data access methods on different classes.

Consider the following example code.

PDO Connection Class

```
class DBService {
    private static $instance = null;
    public static function connect() {
        if(self::$instance === null) {
            try {
                self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=myservername;dbname=mydbname", 'myusername', 'mypassword');
           } catch (\Exception $e) {
               return null;
           }
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    protected function __construct() {} // prevent creating new instance (faking a singleton)
}
```

Order Repository for Database Access

```
class OrderRepository {
    public static function insert($data) {
        $con = DBService::connect();
        $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO Orders (customer_id, order_date) VALUES (:custId, NOW())');
        $stmt->execute(array(':custId'=>$data['custId']));
        return $con->lastInsertId();
    }
}
```

OrderDetailRepository (lineitems) for an order's products

```
class OrderDetailRepository {
    public static function insert($data) {
        $con = DBService::connect();
        $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO OrderDetails (order_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES (:orderId, :prodId, :qty)');
        $stmt->execute(array(':orderId'=>$data['orderId'],  ':prodId'=>$data['prodId'], ':qty'=>$data['qty']));
        return $con->lastInsertId();
    }
}
```

The service class to handle the logic of creating an order (ie Order entry + Order detail entry).  This is where I need help understanding how to implement a transaction so that if there is an error in the 2nd insert (Order Details) I can rollback the work done inserting into the Order table.

```
class OrderService {
    public static function createOrder($data) {
       try {
           $orderId = OrderRepository::insert($data);
           $orderDetailId = OrderDetailRepository::insert($data);

           // Commit transaction
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
           // Roll back transaction
           return false;
       }
       return true;
    }
}
```

I tried to make this question succinct so the code example is as minimalistic as I could make it.  But still I apologize for the verboseness.

Thanks

Comment: Being succinct and providing a complete code is good, no need to apologize for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply wrap the transaction around where you control the flow of activities, in this case in the `OrderService->createOrder()` method

```
class OrderService {
    public static function createOrder($data) {
       try {
           $con = DBService::connect();
           $con->beginTransaction();

           $orderId = OrderRepository::insert($data);
           $orderDetailId = OrderDetailRepository::insert($data);

           // Commit transaction
           $con->commit();
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
           // Roll back transaction
           $con->rollback();
           return false;
       }
       return true;
    }
}
```

Or you could move it back a level and do it around the call to `OrderService->createOrder()`

The method can then be simplified to

```
class OrderService {
    public static function createOrder($data) {
       $orderId = OrderRepository::insert($data);
       $orderDetailId = OrderDetailRepository::insert($data);
    }
}
```

Your main processing loop

```
try {
    $con = DBService::connect();
    $con->beginTransaction();

    $OrderService->createOrder($data);

    $con->commit();

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Roll back transaction
    $con->rollback();
}
```